# laravel validate multiple models

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-4

I would like a best practice for this kind of problem

I have `items`, `categories` and `category_item` table for a many to many relationship

I have 2 models with these validations rules

```
class Category extends Basemodel {

    public static $rules = array(
        'name'   => 'required|min:2|max:255'
    );
....


class Item extends BaseModel {

    public static $rules = array(
        'title'   => 'required|min:5|max:255',
        'content' => 'required'
    );
....


class Basemodel extends Eloquent{

    public static function validate($data){
        return Validator::make($data, static::$rules);
    }
}
```

I don't know how to validate these 2 sets of rules from only one form with category, title and content fields.

For the moment I just have a validation for the item but I don't know what's the best to do:

- create a new set of rules in my controller -> but it seems redundant
- sequentially validate Item then category  -> but I don't know how to handle validations errors, do I have to merges them? and how?
- a 3rd solution I'm unaware of

here is my ItemsController@store method

```
/**
 * Store a newly created item in storage.
 *
 * @return Redirect
 */
public function store()
{
    $validation= Item::validate(Input::all());
    if($validation->passes()){
        $new_recipe = new Item();
        $new_recipe->title    = Input::get('title');
        $new_recipe->content = Input::get('content');
        $new_recipe->creator_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $new_recipe->save();

        return Redirect::route('home')
            ->with('message','your item has been added');
    }
    else{
        return Redirect::route('items.create')->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
    }
}
```

I am very interested on some clue about this subject

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way, as you pointed yourself, is to validate it sequentially:

```
/**
 * Store a newly created item in storage.
 *
 * @return Redirect
 */
public function store()
{
    $itemValidation = Item::validate(Input::all());
    $categoryValidation = Category::validate(Input::all());

    if($itemValidation->passes() and $categoryValidation->passes()){
        $new_recipe = new Item();
        $new_recipe->title    = Input::get('title');
        $new_recipe->content = Input::get('content');
        $new_recipe->creator_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $new_recipe->save();

        return Redirect::route('home')
            ->with('message','your item has been added');
    }
    else{
        return Redirect::route('items.create')
            ->with('errors', array_merge_recursive(
                                    $itemValidation->messages()->toArray(), 
                                    $categoryValidation->messages()->toArray()
                            )
                )
            ->withInput();
    }
}
```

The other way would be to create something like an Item Repository (domain) to orchestrate your items and categories (models) and use a Validation Service (that you'll need to create too) to validate your forms.

[Chris Fidao](https://twitter.com/fideloper) book, [Implementing Laravel](https://leanpub.com/implementinglaravel), explains that wonderfully.

Comment: Thanks Antonio,
your first solution is exactly what I was looking for but as you mention the Repository solution, this is definitely the way to go

Comment: Did you try other laravel books? why did you choose this one?

Comment: Not just because I translated it to my primary language, it's a great book with real world examples and things you can actually use in your current projects. Taylor's book, also a great one, gives us some important info about SOLID principles and the IoC container, but it's mostly about Laravel coding philosophy. And Code Bright is goog, but it's for beginners in Laravel. Also Jeffrey Way's book, about testing, very good for learning TDD, but not really about Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
$validationMessages = 
    array_merge_recursive(
        $itemValidation->messages()->toArray(), 
        $categoryValidation->messages()->toArray());

return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validationMessages)->withInput();
```

and call it in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$validateUser = Validator::make(Input::all(), User::$rules);
$validateRole = Validator::make(Input::all(), Role::$rules);

if ($validateUser->fails() OR $validateRole->fails()) :
    $validationMessages = array_merge_recursive($validateUser->messages()->toArray(), $validateRole->messages()->toArray());

    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validationMessages)->withInput();

endif;
```