# Validating fields from different tables-laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

I am trying to validate fields that will be stored in different tables. In the sales form user has to input quantity_sold. It should not be greater than available_stock. This is what i have so far. It was working just fine but it's currently not accepting any input.

```
$product_availability = Stock::select('available_stock')->where('product_id', $request->product_id)->first();

$rules = array(
        'product_id'             => 'required',                  
        'quantity_sold'=>'max:'.$product_availability,

    );
```

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19145170/3918473

Comment: Gayan- I checked it out but it's different from mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$rules = array(
    'product_id'             => 'required',                  
    'quantity_sold'=>'max:'.$product_availability->available_stock,

);
```

If your **available stock** is integer the change **'quantity_sold'** value in rules array as

```
'integer|max:'.$product_availability->available_stock
```

if **available_stock** is float then you can change **'quantity_sold'** value in rules array as

```
 'numeric|max:'.$product_availability->available_stock
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I had earlier on tried that but it failed, I have no idea why it keeps on changing

Comment: Your $product_availability will give you the object which will consist of available_stock. so you have to fetch available_stock field from that object.It should work, if in any case it failed you can post me your controller whole code. i would be glad to help. you can email me at vikashkrkashyap@gmail.com